# O que significa "malta" que os portugueses usam?

Tags: significado, português-europeu

What's the meaning of "malta" often used by the Portuguese? Is this considered slang?

Comment: Acho que você não está se referindo a ilha de Malta, que fica no mar Mediterrâneo. Correto?

Comment: Claro que não :) Os portugueses sabem. Até eu sei :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Malta é um grupo de pessoas. Pode querer dizer "nós", "a gente", "eles", "a turma", "a galera", etc. Também tem um sentido pejorativo, como "a ralé", a "escória".

Answer (score 13):

Atualmente *malta* é usado praticamente só para designar um grupo de amigos, colegas de trabalho, pessoas que andam frequentemente juntos. Eu tinha apenas uma vaga noção dum outro sentido, trabalhadores agrícolas que se deslocam em grupo longe de casa em busca de trabalho sazonal.

Claro que se perguntarem a um português com mais de trinta anos qual é a primeira coisa que lhe vem à cabeça com a palavra *malta*, quase de certeza terão como resposta a canção revolucionária [o que faz falta](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h4Xy6-QnQko), que usa *malta* possivelmente nos dois sentidos anteriores. Como até eu tive dificuldade em compreender algumas palavras, a [letra está aqui](http://letras.mus.br/zeca-afonso/749116/).

Agora os dicionários dizem realmente que *malta* também significa gente desfavorecida (esses trabalhadores agrícolas eram-no), ralé, grupo de pessoas sem escrúpulos, grupo de pessoas com uma caraterística comum (bando,súcia). Eu nunca tinha ouvido ou lido *malta* com este sentido, até que nos últimos três ou quatro dias encontrei dois possíveis exemplos em dois livros de há mais de um século, de dois Coelhos!

> "Já o andam a desinquietar para ir com os mais furtar a bandeira [isto era parte da tradição da festa anual da aldeia]. (...) Mas o que eu queria, sr.ª Luísa, é que o seu marido [o "juiz" da festa nesse ano] me não deixasse o rapaz ir na malta!" suplicou aflita a rapariga. ([Trindade Coelho](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Francisco_Trindade_Coelho), "Prelúdios de Festa" in [*Os Meus Amores*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Os_Meus_Amores), 1891.)
>
> "(...) [O]uvi uma gritaria e gargalhadas estrondosas que vinham da rua de Santo António -- voltei-me e vi aparecer, à frente de uma malta de garotos, roto, brandindo furiosamente um velho guarda-chuva, o Pinheiro *Chicote*. ([Coelho Netto](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coelho_Neto#Obras), "Away" in *A Bico de Pena*, 1904.)

Para quem não saiba, o segundo Coelho era brasileiro.

Answer (score 3):

malta: povo, galera, multidão.

Comment: Hello Rodrigo and welcome to Portuguese SE. Could you add a reference to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

A palavra "malta" refere-se a um numero de pessoas normalmente colegas ou amigos mas nunca como uma expressão pejorativa. Um sinónimo podia ser "pessoal"
ex:" Aqui a malta está-se a divertir" ou "Aqui o pessoal está-se a divertir"

Comment: Sobre ser pejorativo. Vide https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/malta : "Grupo de pessoas de má índole ou desordeiras"; ou ainda "Gente sem escrúpulos, sem .caráter"

Answer (score 0):

Vem de Malteses, gente solta, jovial e sem responsabilidades nem compromissos, mas prontos a ajudar e a fazer pequenos trabalhos. Aquando da invasão de Malta pelos franceses de Napoleão os militares da Ordem de Malta foram forçados a sair por o seu código de conduta impedir que lutassem contra outros cristãos. Posteriormente Portugal colaborou ativamente para a libertação de Malta.
https://ccm.marinha.pt/pt/museumarinha_web/multimedia_web/Paginas/efemeride-inicio-bloqueio-ilha-malta-19set19.aspx