# Is it offensive to call a little boy a "putinho" in Portugal?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, diferenças-transatlânticas

## In English

I've heard an adult refer to a young boy as **"esse putinho"** and it didn't sound like he meant any offense. In what situations do the Portuguese use it?  Would you expect any reaction if you used the word before the kid's parents?  Can you use the feminine form for little girls?

**PS:** In Brazil, it is offensive. **Never use it.**

---

## Em português

É ofensivo referir-se a um menino como **"um putinho"** em Portugal?  Eu já ouvi adultos referirem-se a meninos como "esses putinhos" e não me pareceu que o objetivo fosse ofender. Em que situações os portugueses usam esse termo?  Se usado na frente dos pais dos meninos, geraria alguma indignação?  E para as meninas, pode-se usar no feminino?

**PS:** No Brasil é sempre ofensivo. **Não use.**

Comment: Talvez não fosse má ideia acrescentar "in Portugal" logo na primeira frase, para ficar claro desde o início que estamos a falar duma peculiaridade de Portugal.

Comment: @Jacinto  Talvez, mas como o PS em negrito está gritante, e na página de perguntas pode-se ler parte da pergunta explicada, acho que não faria muita diferença. De qualquer forma obrigado pela sugestão.

Comment: @Centaurus Thanks for translating that; it should help people distinguish the Portuguese language from the people of Portugal. I’ve tried to make the two halves look the same in emphasis and formatting, but if that isn’t the way you want it, please feel free to edit into whatever you’d like (as always).

Comment: @tchrist Thank you..  Feel free to do it whenever necessary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**ENGLISH**

This applies to *puto* as used in Portugal, and, I think, other Portuguese-speaking countries except Brazil.

*Putinho* is a diminutive form of *puto*, and is not offensive when referring to a young boy.

[*Puto*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/puto) (from Latim *putus*, little boy) is a common, informal word meaning a boy, especially a little one. It emphasises the boy is still a child and junior to speaker. Hence it will be provocative, demeaning, or even offensive to use the word to refer to an adult or older teenager, or for children to use it to refer to a boy of their own age or older. It also implies familiarity, so it will be provocative to use it to address a boy you do not know. It can be a mild term of endearment: a man talking about *his puto* is talking abut his non-adult son.

[*Puta*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/puta) may derive from *puto* (the origin is disputed), but means, informally, a prostitute, and in modern use the two words are as unrelated as two words can be. I'm told that in some circles people are starting to use [*pita*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/pita) as a feminine-in-meaning of *puto*.

*Putozinho* is the diminutive form of *puto* I'm used to, and it means a little *puto*. When applied to a little boy, *putinho* will mean the same.

And for a little more context, just check out [*os putos*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQOWrH-ruvA)  ([lyrics in Portuguese and English here.)](http://lyricstranslate.com/en/os-putos-kids.html)

**PORTUGUÊS**

Isto é sobre o uso de *puto* em Portugal e, creio, nos outros países de língua portuguesa exceto o Brasil.

*Putinho* é um diminutivo de *puto*, e não é ofensivo quando usado para nos referirmos a um menino.

[*Puto*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/puto) (do Latim *putus*, menino) é um termo comum e informal que significa rapaz, especialmente um menino. Enfatiza que o rapaz é ainda uma criança e com estatuto de algum modo inferior ao do locutor. Por isso, é um termo provocador, desrespeitoso ou mesmo ofensivo se for usado em relação a um adulto ou adolescente mais velho, ou se for usado por crianças para se referirem a um rapaz da sua idade ou mais velho. Implica alguma familiaridade, portanto chamar *puto* a um rapaz desconhecido será entendido como provocação. Pode ser um termo algo afetuoso: um homem que fale do *seu puto* refere-se a um filho não adulto.

[*Puta*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/puta) poderá ter a sua origem em *puto* (a origem é controversa), mas significa informalmente prostituta, e não existe no uso atual qualquer relação entre as duas palavras. Constou-me que nalguns círculos se começou a usar [*pita*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/pita) como equivalente feminino de *puto*.

*Putozinho* é o diminutivo de *puto* que eu estou mais habituado a ouvir. Quando aplicado a um menino, *putinho* significa o mesmo.

E para uma melhor compreensão do uso da palavra em Portugal vejam [*os putos*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQOWrH-ruvA) e, se necessário, [a letra está aqui](http://lyricstranslate.com/en/os-putos-kids.html).

Comment: Realmente a música é muito linda.  Já estou me acostumando com esse uso de "puto" ou "putinho" mas para um brasileiro que nunca ouviu, isso soa muito estranho. No mínimo provocaria muitos risos.

Comment: @Centaurus A canção traduz bem a maneira como a palavra _puto_ é percebida em Portugal. Mas imagino bem a reação que a palavra provoque nos ouvidos dum brasileiro que não conheça o seu uso em Portugal. Até a mim _putinho_, por não estar habituado a ouvir (ao contrário de _putozinho_; é capaz de variar de região para região), me causa uma certa estranheza. E teria ficado na dúvida se não soubesse que foi usada a respeito dum rapazinho. De qualquer modo, para um garoto com uns cinco anos ou mais, na minha opinião _puto_ é suficiente; o "inho" já estaria a mais.

Comment: Só de realçar que se dissermos "és um puto" para um adulto pode ter uma conotação negativa "és muito imaturo".

Comment: Para complementar o comentário do @JorgeB. , na subcultura hip-hop portuguesa "puto" é equivalente a "bro". Não só para designar jovens - ver o uso por *Da Weasel* em várias letras, por exemplo: `para os meus putos a cumprir pena na prisão`.

Comment: @ANeves Interessante, não sabia dessa.

Comment: @Centaurus A canção inclui a expressão "capitães da malta." Eu lembrava-me dessa passagem, mas só a compreendi plenamente depois de me envolver na pergunta aqui do SE [sobre "malta" em Portugal](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/54/o-que-significa-malta-que-os-portugueses-usam)!

Answer (score 0):

Realmente a palavra putinho usa-se muito pouco mas nunca seria uma ofensa pelo menos em Portugal.

Answer (score 0):

acho que ninguém ia entender

Chamar puto implica familiaridade, não se usa entre desconhecidos

Comment: Mas é provocativo quando usado com um desconhecido, como mencionado noutra [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/1057/2764)?

Answer (score -1):

In Brazil, this expression can used when the person feels hate or rage, or when a young guy made something wrong - like breaking something.

The expected reaction of the other person is to argue and maybe fight verbally.

For girls: **essa putinha**

Feminine nouns and adjectives are formed by changing the ending **-o** (in the masculine version) to an **a**.

Comment: Felipe, the question is about the use of the word "putinho" by the Portuguese, which is completely different from Brazilian usage.

Comment: But where is "Portuguese Portugal"

Comment: Felippe, a palavra "the Portuguese" na frase da pergunta "In what situations do the Portuguese use it?" só pode significar "os portugueses". Para significar "a língua portuguesa" teria de ser "does (...) use" em vez de "do (...) use," e não sei se ficava uma frase muito natural. Imagino que para quem não esteja a par da peculiaridade da palavra _puto_ em Portugal, essa diferençazinha possa passar despercebida. Eu vi logo o que é que a pergunta queria por ser de Portugal. Se começares a tua primeira frase com "In Brazil, this expression...", apesar de não responder à pergunta, complementa.

Comment: A pergunta foi editada em Português, Felippe.

Comment: @FelippeTadeu editei a resposta para a melhorar. Mas continuo a achar que esta resposta não é adequada para a pergunta feita.

Comment: Ok desculpe não havia entendido