# "Ao mandar o Bernardo às compras..." Is this an idiom?

Tags: diferenças-transatlânticas, expressões-idiomáticas

I've read in a newspaper **"Ao mandar o Bernardo às compras será preciso usar durex."** It was quoted as a sentence in ptPT which would certainly confuse a Brazilian reader, but there was no explanation why it might do so.  I know that "durex" means a condom in ptPT, and "scotch tape" in ptBR.

My question is: Is "mandar o Bernardo às compras" an idiom or should I understand it literally for what it is?

Comment: @E_net4 I read it in a newspaper article written by a Brazilian reported who visited Portugal. He comments on several differences between ptBR and ptPT and ends his column saying: "Ao mandar o Bernardo......." but leaves this one unexplained.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**ENGLISH**

**Mandar o Bernardo às compras** (send Bernardo to buy something) would have most Portuguese confused too. According to [my sources](https://www.facebook.com/PortugueseSayings/posts/361764137260344) it is an Azorean expression, meaning *to copulate*. It has even made it to the [Dicionário Informal](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/mandar%20o%20bernardo%20%C3%A0s%20compras/), which is not terribly precise about where it is used. One interpretation is that the couple would send the kid, Bernardo, to the shop to have a little privacy. But Italians may have interpreted *Bernardo* differently, for according to [this German book on Italian erotic language](https://books.google.pt/books?id=9EEQ48a6H_8C&pg=PA279&dq=%22mandar%20o%20bernardo%20%C3%A0s%20compras%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAmoVChMI-YGO76ypyAIVhuwUCh2ikAs_#v=onepage&q=%22mandar%20o%20bernardo%20%C3%A0s%20compras%22&f=false) the phrase gave rise to the Italian word [*bernarda*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bernarda), which does not mean *little girl* at all.

**PORTUGUÊS**

**Mandar o Bernardo às compras** confundiria também a maioria dos portugueses. De acordo com [as minhas fontes](https://www.facebook.com/PortugueseSayings/posts/361764137260344) é uma expressão açoriana que significa *copular*. Até já chegou ao [Dicionário Informal](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/mandar%20o%20bernardo%20%C3%A0s%20compras/), que não é particularmente preciso sobre onde ela é conhecida. Uma interpretação é que o casal mandaria o [puto](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1055/is-it-offensive-to-call-a-little-boy-a-putinho-in-portugal#answer-1057), o Bernardo, às compras para ter um bocadinho de privacidade. Mas os italianos devem ter interpretado *Bernardo* de outro modo, pois de acordo com este [livro alemão sobre linguagem erótica italiana](https://books.google.pt/books?id=9EEQ48a6H_8C&pg=PA279&dq=%22mandar%20o%20bernardo%20%C3%A0s%20compras%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAmoVChMI-YGO76ypyAIVhuwUCh2ikAs_#v=onepage&q=%22mandar%20o%20bernardo%20%C3%A0s%20compras%22&f=false) a expressão deu origem à palavra italiana [*bernarda*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bernarda), que não tem nada a ver com *menina*.

Comment: That's what I thought it migh be. A very funny way of saying it... lol.

Comment: Reminds me of the English expression "I have to see a man about a dog" which doesn't mean the same but uses a euphemistic sentence too.

Comment: It is funny. I'm going to ask an Azorean friend of mine about it.

Comment: Também nunca tinha ouvido eu.

Comment: Jacinto, my cousin from Terceira, Azores, says he never heard it.  I wonder where in Portugal people have heard it.